# blogengine.net to sharepoint blog

Tags: migration, blog

I am using blogengine.net blog but I want to migrate it to a SharePoint 2010 foundation blog. Is there any way to make it automatically? Is there a such tool to help me?

Comment: Thanks for sharing such valuable information.It will surely going to help me a lot to solve my queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These companies produce software to help with migration.

- http://www.tzunami.com/products.php?did=11
- http://www.metalogix.com/products/migration-manager-for-sharepoint/Blogs-and-Wikis-Edition.aspx
- http://www.idera.com/Products/SharePoint/SharePoint-migration-suite/

*(Not affiliated with and never used any of them)*

None specifically mention blogengine.net but I believe that they can all work with misc 'websites'

Most of them offer white papers giving tips on what to look out for when doing a migration.

If none of them fit the bill then you could 'roll your own' solution using [SharePoints Content Migration API](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2007/08/30/deep-dive-into-the-sharepoint-content-deployment-and-migration-api-part-1.aspx).

Finally - unless you have thousands of pages it may be more cost effective doing this manually, be pragmatic about it.

Comment: The listed softwares help to migrate some apps. to sharepoint. However as far as I reviewed none of them migrates blogs to sharepoint from blogengine.Net.  Still thanks for enlighting.

Comment: As I said, I think that some of them can do general 'websites' so whilst they don't specifically work with blogengine then can see it as a website